# SearchConfiguration is not configured correctly. ContentSearchConfiguration was expected but System.String was returned

Tags: configuration, solr

I am getting this error when trying to access a Sitecore website. Here's a screenshot of the complete error message.

[image]

It probably has to do with configuring Solr to work with Sitecore. Does anyone have any idea what the source of the problem might be?

Comment: Missing config files. Do you have `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config` and other indexes configs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have enabled all of those config files.

Comment: Do you have computed field in solr & are you missing any patch-up configuration. If yes please see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676869/simple-sitecore-include-file-gone-wrong-computedindexfields-config

Comment: I came across this same issue. The Solr Support package was missing, along with a nuget package for the IoC binaries. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Initial_Release.aspx Further reading:
http://blog.alpha-solutions.us/2016/10/how-to-use-solr-with-sitecore-8-2-with-solr-6-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what version of Sitecore you are using but have you checked the following steps?

1. All Lucene config files (`Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.*`) have been renamed to .disabled in wwwroot\\App_Config\Include.
2. All Solr configs are enabled, those that follow this pattern: `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.*` (there is a good script for this here: https://gist.github.com/patrickperrone/59b8745ee8b8ff9045b5)
3. You have set the value of `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` and `ContentSearch.Provider` is set to `"Solr"`.
4. You have set the Solr processor to `"Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorInitializeSolrProvider"` here: `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`.
5. Rebuild your indexes
6. Check your custom indexes and custom search index configuration

**More info here:** https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr#_Configuring_Sitecore_to

This is also a bit out of date for the latest version of Sitecore but is a nice walk-through:

https://born4joy.wordpress.com/2015/09/03/installation-and-configuration-of-solr-for-sitecore-8/

One other thing worth checking is how you are configuring your IOC for Solr, it can be done like so in the Global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Language=’C#’ Inherits=”Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorApplication” %>
```

In our 8.1 site We are doing this via WebActivatorEx instead but it does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the info man. Step 4 is the one I missed. The problem is that my Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config file doesn't have the <initialize> pipeline where I can set the Solr processor. I tried adding it but that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same issue and resolved by disabled all lucene indexes and enabling all solr indexed.

Please dont go by filename to disable the indexes. first enable lucene and go to index manager and note down all index names then disable.

In my case, I have missed mediaframework_brightcove index because it doesn't have name with lucene.

Enable all Solr indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. In my case, the Sitecore.MediaFramework.config file was the one that was causing issues. Disabling that got rid of the error.